# How to move gmail messages with label to a folder after 7 days

Tags: google-apps-script

I have added a label to messages as noted in the lifehacker link below.

I would like to have client emails labeled "clients" moved to the INBOX/Clients folder after 7 days.

Thanks in advance!

I know that there is a [code for cleaning the mail-box](http://lifehacker.com/5986204/automatically-clean-up-gmail-on-a-schedule-with-this-script)

```
function cleanUp() {
    var delayDays = 2 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash
    var maxDate = new Date();
    maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - delayDays);
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("delete me");
    var threads = label.getThreads();
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate() < maxDate) {
            threads[i].moveToTrash();
        }
    }
}
```

But I need to move emails. How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than linking to an off-site script, please provide a [mcve] within your question. This will make it easier for other users to help you, and will ensure that your question is still valid if the site you linked to goes down. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function moveUp() {
    var delayDays = 7 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash
    var maxDate = new Date();
    maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - delayDays);
    var label1 = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("clients1"); // FROM
    var label2 = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("clients2"); // TO
    var threads = label1.getThreads();
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate() < maxDate) {
            threads[i].addLabel(label2).removeLabel(label1).moveToArchive();
        }
    }
}
```

- `label1` is from-label
- `label1` is to-label

You could erase `.moveToArchive()` if you don't need to archive the thread.